# Is there a way to route processes better?

Tags: c, linux

I try to create a process tree with fork() so that the number of children per parent is in a given array, for example if the array is {2,1,3,0,0,0,0} the tree will look like this:

```
                |   a   |
                /       \
             | b |     |  c  |
             /         /  |  \                 
          | d |   | e | | f | | g |
```

I am able to create processes and separate the parent process from the child process by checking whether the value returned from fork() is 0.
And I managed to create a process tree, but the tree I manage to create is symmetrical, and not what I really want to build.
I can not figure out the part of routing processes between siblings,

How can I check for each process separately how many children should create for it, and create for it without creating for the other sibling processes?

This is what i got so far:

```c
int main() {
    int nums[7] = { 2,1,3,0,0,0,0 };
    int pid, pid2;
    size_t len = sizeof(nums)/sizeof(int);
    int childs2;
        printf("\nProcess number %d has pid= %d\n", 0, getpid());
        int childs = 1;
        while( childs <= nums[0] ) {
            pid = fork();
            if (pid == 0 ) {
                printf("Process number %d has pid= %d\n", childs, getpid());
                printf("I am Process with pid=%d and my parent pid=%d\n", getpid(), getppid());
                waitpid(getppid());
                for (int i=1; i<len; i++) {
                    childs2 = 0;
                    if (childs2 < nums[i]) {
                        pid2 = fork();
                        if (pid2 == 0) {
                            printf("Process number %d has pid= %d\n", childs, getpid());
                            printf("I am Process with pid=%d and my parent pid=%d\n", getpid(), getppid());
                            waitpid(getppid());
                            break;
                        } else {
                            wait(NULL);
                            childs2++;
                        }
                    } else {
                        childs2++;
                    }
                }
                break;
            } else {
            wait(NULL);
            childs++;
            }
        }
    return 0;
}
```

I have to differentiate between the processes to know which process is a leaf and which process is a parent. To do this I need to perform a different action in each process and I can not think of a way to do it,

my output is :

```
Process number 0 has pid= 98431
Process number 1 has pid= 98432
I am Process with pid=98432 and my parent pid=98431
Process number 1 has pid= 98433
I am Process with pid=98433 and my parent pid=98432
Process number 1 has pid= 98434
I am Process with pid=98434 and my parent pid=98432
Process number 2 has pid= 98435
I am Process with pid=98435 and my parent pid=98431
Process number 2 has pid= 98436
I am Process with pid=98436 and my parent pid=98435
Process number 2 has pid= 98437
I am Process with pid=98437 and my parent pid=98435
```

and the tree is look like:

```
                |   a   |
                /       \
             | b |      | c |
             /   \      /   \                 
          | d | | e || f | | g |
```

but i want the output to be:

```
Process number 0 has pid= 98431
Process number 1 has pid= 98432
I am Process with pid=98432 and my parent pid=98431
Process number 2 has pid= 98433
I am Process with pid=98433 and my parent pid=98431
Process number 3 has pid= 98434
I am Process with pid=98434 and my parent pid=98432
Process number 4 has pid= 98435
I am Process with pid=98435 and my parent pid=98433
Process number 5 has pid= 98436
I am Process with pid=98436 and my parent pid=98433
Process number 6 has pid= 98437
I am Process with pid=98437 and my parent pid=98433
```

so the tree will look like:

```
                |   a   |
                /       \
             | b |     |  c  |
             /         /  |  \                 
          | d |   | e | | f | | g |
```

.

Comment: You could use socketpair to send the child the pointer to array, where it has to build its subtree.
See https://gist.github.com/yinyin/0682a957450f7abb7f76603da2d3b8d5 for socketpair example. 
Then if you are the parent, send the child the pointer of the &nums[childOffset] and remaining length (size of array - childOffset).

Comment: Did the compiler warn you about excess initializers in `int nums[6] = { 2,1,3,0,0,0,0 };`?

Comment: Start by clearing out the warnings. Compile with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` for less frustration in life.

Comment: The code is going to have to step through the `nums` array carefully, with each process determining which entry it is processing.  The original parent needs to create two processes, and the first needs to know that it is supposed to process `nums[1]` and the second that it is supposed to process `nums[2]`.  With more elaborate process hierarchies (`int nums[] = { 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };` for example), the third level processes need to know where to find their own entry and how to tell their children to find their entries.  I've not worked out the algorithm, but …

Answer (score 2):

What we need to do is keep track of what process we are within the list and where the children are within the list. The following code shows how to do this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <unistd.h>


#define NumberOf(a) (sizeof (a) / sizeof *(a))


/*  Create children for process p.

    In a child, return the number of that child process.
    In the parent, return -1.
*/
static int CreateChildren(int NumberOfChildren[], int FirstChild[], int p)
{
    //  Create children for process p.
    printf("Process %d has pid %u and parent %u.\n",
        p, (unsigned) getpid(), (unsigned) getppid());

    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfChildren[p]; ++i)
    {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid == -1)
        {
            perror("fork");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (pid == 0)
            /*  This is a child process, and it is child i of process p, so
                its process number is FirstChild[p] + i.  Return that.
            */
            return p = FirstChild[p] + i;
    }

    //  Wait for children to finish.
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfChildren[p]; ++i)
        wait(0);

    //  Tell caller the parent finished.
    return -1;
}


int main(void)
{
    int NumberOfChildren[] = { 2, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    size_t N = NumberOf(NumberOfChildren);

    // Check the NumberOfChildren array for consistency.    
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (size_t n = 0; n < N; ++n)
        {
            if (NumberOfChildren[n] < 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr,
                    "Error, number of children cannot be negative but is %d.\n",
                    NumberOfChildren[n]);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            sum += NumberOfChildren[n];
        }

        if (sum != N-1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,
                "Error, the numbers of children sum to %d desecendants "
                "of the root, but array has %zu elements after the root "
                "element.\n",
                sum, N-1);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    /*  Compile information about the children -- set FirstChild[n] to the
        index of the element in NumberOfChildren that is for the first child
        of process n.
    */
    int FirstChild[N];
    {
        int NextChild = 1;
        for (int n = 0; n < N; ++n)
        {
            FirstChild[n] = NextChild;
            NextChild += NumberOfChildren[n];
        }
    }

    //  This is the root process.  Set p to its index.
    int p = 0;

    /*  Create children for process p.  When a child is created, it will
        return its process number, and we will loop to create children for it.
    */
    while (p >= 0)
        p = CreateChildren(NumberOfChildren, FirstChild, p);
}
```

Sample output:

```
Process 0 has pid 2648 and parent 2641.
Process 1 has pid 2649 and parent 2648.
Process 2 has pid 2650 and parent 2648.
Process 3 has pid 2651 and parent 2649.
Process 4 has pid 2652 and parent 2650.
Process 5 has pid 2653 and parent 2650.
Process 6 has pid 2654 and parent 2650.
```